# How do I update data-source based on dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I have the desired output I need for the p1 plot from the callback attached to the select widget's js_on_change function. It displays the correct data on the javascript console but is not updating on the p1 plot. I have a similar question which got solved before but for whatever reason its not working for this case. Might have something to do with the select.js_on_change but im not sure.

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data={
        'CAUSE' : df.cause_of_death,
        'AGE_GROUP' : df.AGE_GROUP,
        'YEAR' : df.YEAR, 
        'DEATHS' : df.deaths, 
        'RATE' : df.rate, 
        })

rangeMax = 1800

#converting matplotlib colour map to fkin bokeh ones >:(
colormap =cm.get_cmap("gist_heat_r") #choose any matplotlib colormap here
bokehpalette = [plt.colors.rgb2hex(m) for m in colormap(np.arange(colormap.N))]

mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette = bokehpalette, low=min(df.deaths), high=rangeMax)

age_group = list(df.AGE_GROUP)

p1 = figure(title="Deaths caused by lung cancer in Australia from ({0} - {1})".format(yearMin, yearMax),
           x_range=[yearMin, yearMax], 
           y_range=[age_group[0], age_group[1], age_group[2], age_group[3], age_group[4], age_group[5], age_group[6], age_group[7], age_group[8], 
                    age_group[9], age_group[10], age_group[11], age_group[12], age_group[13], age_group[14], age_group[15]], 
                    plot_width = 800, 
                    plot_height = 350, 
                    tools = TOOLS, toolbar_location=None)

p1.grid.grid_line_color = None
p1.axis.axis_line_color = None
p1.axis.major_tick_line_color = None
p1.xaxis.axis_label = 'Year'
p1.yaxis.axis_label = 'Age Group'
p1.axis.major_label_text_font_size = "8pt"
p1.axis.major_label_standoff = 0
p1.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi / 3

rc = p1.rect(x="YEAR", y="AGE_GROUP", width=1, height=1,
       source=source, 
       fill_color={'field': 'DEATHS', 'transform': mapper},
       line_color='white')


callback = CustomJS(args = {'rect': rc.data_source.data, 'source': source}, 
code = """
var x = source.data
var select = cb_obj.value


var data = {"AGE_GROUP": [],  "CAUSE": [], "DEATHS": [], "RATE": [], "YEAR": []}

var indices = x.CAUSE.map((e,i) => e === select ? i : '').filter(x => x)


for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++){     
    data.AGE_GROUP.push(x.AGE_GROUP[indices[i]])
}
for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++){     
    data.CAUSE.push(x.CAUSE[indices[i]])
}
for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++){     
    data.DEATHS.push(x.DEATHS[indices[i]])
}
for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++){     
    data.RATE.push(x.RATE[indices[i]])
}
for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++){     
    data.YEAR.push(x.YEAR[indices[i]])
}
console.log(x)
rect = {"AGE_GROUP": data.AGE_GROUP, "CAUSE": data.CAUSE, "DEATHS": data.DEATHS, "RATE": data.RATE, "YEAR": data.YEAR, }
console.log(rect)
"""
)

menu = ["Lung cancer (ICD-10 C33, C34)", "Prostate cancer (ICD-10 C61)", "Colorectal cancer (ICD-10 C18–C20, C26.0)", "Breast cancer (ICD-10 C50)"]
select = Select(title="Option:", value=menu[0], options=menu)
select.js_on_change('value', callback)
```

The ideal solution is that when someone clicks an option on the dropdown menu it populates the rect plot based on that value i.e lung cancer will display the data for lung cancer. 
Attached the code and data if anyone needs a deeper dive. 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11jfrpQnDOsECyjB96CXxgUK4cDhJIbcK?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new *local variable* `data` and then doing nothing with it. It is discarded with no effect when the callback code ends. Bokeh responds when its objects properties are set by assigning to the properties *on the objects*, which you are not doing. If `source` is the data source that drives whatever glyph you want to update, you need to do:

```
source.data = data
```

The same is true of `rect`. You are making *new, local variables*. They exist in the scope of the callback function code, then disappear. Bokeh has no way to see or do anything with these.